# Set Operations in the Unix Shell

Tags: shell-scripting, unix

Set operations in the unix shell are possible:

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell/

And the solutions from this site are very user-friendly. With "user"  being a sub set of all people loving unix :-)

I search a library to do things like this:

```
set-ops fileA - fileB
```

With "fileX" being a set of lines in a file.

I want a easy to use tool:

- The tool can use some kind of sorting for the implementation, but me (the user) don't want to call it.
- I don't want to call "comm -3" or other things which are hard to remember.

This results into the restriction that the set members are strings which must not contain the newline character. But that's ok.

Needed features:

- open source
- easy to install (for me this means: rpm/dpkg/pip package)
- available on linux.
- Above link has a list of supported set operations (Set Membership to Maximum). Most of them should be implemented.

Comment: You want to do everything within the shell?

Comment: @BillBell what is "shell"? If I call a command like grep or sed, then there is not big difference to calling a special command, or a python/perl script. Short answer: I want to call the set operations tool via shell. I don't care at all about the implementation (it can be python, perl, c, go, ....). Dear Bill, did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a python script to make set operations available on the command line.

Source Code is here: [https://github.com/guettli/reprec/blob/master/setops/**init**.py](https://github.com/guettli/reprec/blob/master/setops/__init__.py)

Since I wanted it to be ready before this bounty finishes, the source is in the repo of my reprec tool.

You can install it via pip: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reprec

Usage:

```
===> setops -h
usage: setops [-h] set1 operator set2

Operators: 
  union Aliases: | + or
  intersection Aliases: & and
  difference Aliases: - minus
  symmetric_difference Aliases: ^

positional arguments:
  set1
  operator
  set2

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Neat. Well done.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder why you did not mention his other post: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/set-operations-in-unix-shell-simplified/ that actually has the list of most set operations - the the scripts are available for download as `.txt`.

Comment: Have you looked at the text file? It does not provide commands for the shell. I think it is just an other format (text instead of html).

Comment: Yeah, I know. The question is - is this the sort of thing you are looking for or you want a custom script library, where say: `set_union file1 file2 ... filen` executes `cat set1 set2 ... setn` and say `set_min set` fires away `head -1 <(sort set)`?

Answer (score 0):

I might as well say what I was thinking when I commented! :)

Have you considered using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/)? It has a fairly complete collection of set operations, and also allows Python code within itself. If the text files you contemplate manipulating are not too large then you could write a quite small routine to convert a text file to a Sage set then use the Sage operators to manipulate instances of these sets.

Comment: If I have two files like in the question text (fileA, fileB). The content is newline separated filenames. How can I do set operations on the shell with Sage?

Comment: You can write Sage scripts that are callable from the shell. See http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/programming.html#standalone-python-sage-scripts.

Comment: Hmm Sage is GPL. I am afraid that I need to open source my scripts which use Sage, since the GPL is a viral licence.